# How to get controls from ItemTemplate in ItemsControl in code behind?

Tags: wpf

I have a `MenuItem` that loads sub menu items in `ItemsControl`.

```
<MenuItem  SubmenuOpened="MenuItem_OnSubmenuOpened"  Style="{StaticResource MenuItemImageStyle}" >
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WorkshopList}" x:Name="ItemsControl"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-35 0"  >
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" x:Name="MenuItem"  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.LeaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemImageStyle}" Padding="20">
    </MenuItem>
   </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
</MenuItem>
```

I want to focus first item of `ItemsControl` when open submenu.

I use `SubmenuOpened` event, and want to find first item and focus it. but How do i get controls of `ItemsControl`.

```
 var container = ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ItemsControl.Items.CurrentItem) as FrameworkElement;
```

but container is null.

Comment: Why have an ItemsControl as MenuItem Content when MenuItem is itself already an ItemsControl?

Comment: Thanks, i use menuitem itemcontrols, but how to get focus first menu item?